# Find the max outer side sum of a hexagon made with triangles

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a problem with triangles.

I have 6 triangles for example this:
[image]

And each triangle have a value en each side. The problem is that I can move the triangle and I can rotate them. I have to create a hexagon like this:

[image]

I have to add the outer side of the triangles and get the maximum score. In this example is 152.

And the inner sides must be equal
For example 3 with 3, 2 eith 2, 5 with 5, 7 with 4 with 4 and 1 with 1.

I am doing this in C++.

I save each triangle in an array.

```
int triangle[6][3];
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    cin>>triangle[i][0]>>triangle[i][1]>>triangle[i][2];
```

And I intend to compare the last element of the array with the other elements, but it does not work.

Who can give me an idea to do this problem? Because I do not know how can I generate all the possible combinations for the triangle to create the hexagon, and a way to not search in the same array other time, and how do I have to add to obtain the scores.

There may be cases where the hexagon can not be formed.

With the last element can be the possibility that I can no formed the triangle, then I need rotate the triangle to formed the hexagon.

Comment: "And i am intending to compare the last element of the array with the other elements, but it does not work." - why do you try to compare the *last* element? also, you haven't posted any code, how could we help?

Comment: Because with the last element can be the posibility that i can no formed the triangle, then i need rotate the triangle to formed the hexagon.

Comment: Note that in your sample, you are reading off the end of your array in the 2nd cin element: "triangle[i][3]"  That 3 should be a 1.

Comment: If you brute force this by trying every possible hexagon it could still finish in a few seconds (try every ordering of the triangles and then every orientation => `6! * 3^6` < 1 million). That brute force could be heavily optimized to probably run in <1s. Do you need this to be extensible to larger data sets? Perhaps, not just a hexagon, but an `n`-sided polygon?

Answer (score 1):

I will develop this logic. You write the code.

1. Our goal is to get the **maximum sum** => we want the **highest values** at the **outside**
   The sides of a triangle which are not free i.e. those inside then should ideally take the least values
2. Search for the minimum value taken by a side of a triangle inside the triangle array
3. Does any other triangle also have a side with this value
4. If no, proceed to the next minimum (this may belong to the side of a totally different triangle) and then go back to step 3
5. Suppose there are n such triangles
6. Consider one of them say (n - i) th one (where i is the no. of times u have come back to step 6)...**These 2 triangles are now fused along the matching side**
7. Each of these triangles now has **2 free sides**
8. Compare with other triangles to see if they have matching sides
9. Some triangle has to match. **In the hexagon, each triangle has only one free side.** If **no match** is found for any one of the triangles, it means the **hexagon cannot be formed.**
10. If match(es) are found, consider (n - j) th one (where j is the no. of times u have come back to step 10) of them...proceed
    //
11. At the end 6th triangle does not match both sides of the 2 triangles in which the gap is left, go back to higher step
12. If that step fails go to step..
    //....
13. If that fails go to step 10.
14. If that fails go to step 6

Comment: Seems pretty long now that I have written all that :)

Comment: I do not understand very well your idea, you say me that i find the minimum value in the matrix. In the example case is 1. (1 4 20) later and later search the minimum value of the other 2 sides, for example in this case is 4 later. i have to search a 4 in the matrix. In the example is (4 7 50), later i have to find the minimum of the other sides, that in this case is 7, and etc. And if i and if I finish and I have not found any way to do the hexagon?.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle Consider edit!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm:

Pick a triangle. Call it **A**. (In this example, the 1-4-20 triangle.)

Iterate over the sides of **A**; pick a side (e.g. 1) and suppose it will be an outer side. The next side (4) must be an inner side, so find all other triangles that can match that side (in this case there is only one, 4-7-50). Iterate over this list, looking for a match for the next inner side (50). Continue until you have found all possible hexagons for this choice of a side of **A**.

Once you have iterated over all sides of **A** and found all possible hexagons, pick the one with the highest score.

Is there a part of this that is difficult? Do you need help with the data structures?

**EDIT:**

I'd suggest learning better containers that arrays, but that can be another day.

The function should take two arrays as arguments, and return one. (And maybe some numbers to indicate the lengths of the arrays.) The two arguments are 1) a partial hexagon, and 2) the rest of the triangles. The return value is the best hexagon that can be made from those; it may be empty.

Suppose we call the function with

```
{(3,1,5)}, {(1,4,20), (50,2,3), (5,2,7), (7,5,20), (4,7,50)}
```

The function looks for a match for 5, and finds two possible matches: (5,2,7) and (5,20,7). So it makes two recursive calls,

```
{(3,1,5), (5,2,7)}, {(1,4,20), (50,2,3), (7,5,20), (4,7,50)}
```

and

```
{(3,1,5), (5,20,7)}, {(1,4,20), (50,2,3), (5,2,7), (4,7,50)}
```

It receives two hexagons (at most) from these calls, compares them, and returns the better one.

Comment: And how can i found all possible hexagons for this choice of a side, for example i have the first side is 1 4 20. I do a for example 20 is my outer side then 1 and 4 are my inner sides, then i have to find a 4 in the array, and i can find some 4. which 4 i choise?

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle: Are you familiar with the idea of a breadth-first search?

Comment: I have to use a tree?

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle: you don't need such a data structure, if you are familiar with recursion. I suggest a function that takes a partial hexagon and a list of free triangles, and returns the best hexagon that can be made from that start.

Comment: i do not understand, i am working in c++. for this example the triangles are: 1,4,20 --3,1,5 --50,2,3 --5,2,7 -- 7,5,20--4,7,50. then i am create a function triangle. What recive this function?

Comment: void triangle(int array[][3])?? where that is the matrix with all triangles?